# How to expose the wsdl file using JBoss

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jboss, wsdl

I have a wsdl file in my local hard disk. I would like to expose that using the JBoss Server so that the url which it gives can be given to clients who intend to use the exposed methods.
How can I achieve this ?

I would appreciate if anyone can share an example on how to expose methods(using JBoss Server).

Thanks
-Aj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.namespace.QName.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/‌​String;)V** error when I was trying to run the jboss. Well this was solved on including the latest jaxrpc(replacing the one which I had) in endorsed folder(of lib).

Answer (score 0):

If you place the WSDL in Tomcat web directory, it will be exposed over HTTP(S).  On JBoss 4.x - that directory is `<jboss_home>/server/<your-instance-name>/deploy/jboss-web.deployer/ROOT.war`

Comment: I have created something called 'ws.jar' and placed it under             "jboss-4.2.2.GA\server\default\deploy\ws.jar". I have META-INF folder and other folder(named serverside) with class files in it. In META-INF folder, I have Manifest and ejb-jar.xml.   On starting the jboss, i get the following error. ----------- " java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.namespace.QName.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V "